# Regarding codes gluing django and facebook

Tags: django, facebook

I'm building a website using django and planning to connect it with facebook. I googled and found so many codes to do the job but don't know which one is good for me. I need facebook connect and new graph api support. Could anyone share me some experiences with codes below and advise me which one is good for me? (with some tips if possbible)

- github.com/benbinary/django-facebookconnect
- github.com/dickeytk/django_facebook_oauth
- github.com/digvan/django_facebook_oauth
- github.com/facebook/python-sdk
- github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration
- github.com/ryanmark/django-facebookconnect
- github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk is official Facebook Graph SDK from Facebook. So it's good for fetching/puting data from Facebook. It's doing it well, so you don't have to search for alternative.

Authentication is bit more problem. I was searching for library witch will match my needs, but not found it. So I wrote bit off code myself.

see also:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomasz. I tried ryanmark's one over the weekend and managed to get it work. Though it supports facebook connect, it doesn't seem to support graph api. Is there any way to use graph api on ryanmark's library? Or do I better use official library?

Comment: I also found that the official facebook javascript api (http://github.com/facebook/connect-js) is different from the one I used in xd_receiver.html (http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js). I got confused. Do I better change it with the official one?

Comment: There are two versions of JavaScript library. If you have xd_receiver file you are using "old JavaScript SDK" (in current version there is no such file).
Changing to new version is (almost) always good idea. But you don't have to.
If you have old authorization ("Connect"), I don't know if it works with graph API. New authorization system is called "oAuth".
Sum up: many developers still use old API, so you will not be leaved behind if you start using it. But of course I recommend new API (oAuth + JavaScript SDK + graph API).

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. Is there any django example with the official facebook python-sdk? It seems all of the examples listed there are for google appengine.